# Why are these UIImages glitching when they reload on the screen?:

Tags: ios, objective-c

In my code, after the frog jumps on the lily pad, the lilypad fades out slowly, (making it look like they are submerged) and then after they pass the bottom of the screen, they reload on the top of the screen. The code is as follows:

```
if (CGRectIntersectsRect(FrogSquare.frame, lilypadTS.frame) && (upMovement <= -1) && (swim == YES) && (startingice.hidden == NO)){
    [self bounce];
    [self iceblockfall];
    if (lilypadused == NO) {
        addedScore = 1;
        lilypadused = YES;
    }

    //hide pad
     [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
     [UIView setAnimationDuration:4];
     [startingice setAlpha:0];
     [UIView commitAnimations];

     [self performSelector:@selector(hidePad) withObject:self afterDelay:4.0];
}
```

That part works fine, the lily pad does what its supposed to do. The following is where I get this weird glitch:

```
if (lilypad.center.y > 610) {
    RandomPosition = arc4random() %248;
    RandomPosition = RandomPosition + 36;
    lilypad.center = CGPointMake(RandomPosition, -22);
    lilypadused = NO;

    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:0];
    [lilypad setAlpha:1];
    [UIView commitAnimations];
    [self performSelector:@selector(showlilypad) withObject:self afterDelay:0];

} else if ((lilypad.center.y > 610) && (lilypad.hidden == YES)) {
    RandomPosition = arc4random() %248;
    RandomPosition = RandomPosition + 36;
    lilypad.center = CGPointMake(RandomPosition, -22);
    lilypadused = NO;

    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:0];
    [lilypad setAlpha:1];
    [UIView commitAnimations];
    [self performSelector:@selector(showlilypad) withObject:self afterDelay:0];
}
```

What happens is for some reason, the lilypads will reload at the top of the screen like they're supposed to, but then as the user is jumping on lilypads below the ones at the top. If thats confusing -- Screen Dimensions 320 x 568, lilypad1 reloads at the top of the screen point = -22, then slowly falls down, so say point is 10 after falling for a bit, say the player jumps on lilypad2 that HAS NOT been hidden and gone past 610 (to reload at the top), it makes lilypad1 hide instantly, why is this??

Answer (score 2):

The amount of code you've provided really isn't enough to diagnose your problem. You are likely (definitely) referencing the incorrect lilypad which is causing the errant behavior. You should probably take a close look at the architecture of your app to make sure you are properly managing the list of lilypads in the best way.

Also, whenever you use delays - note that those delays are approximate, not exact. It is possible that you are in a race condition, where the hide has yet to occur but you're already showing it again at the top, then the hide triggers later.

Lastly, if afterDelay is 0 you might as well just call the showlilypad method directly - no need to really delay for 0 seconds.

Good luck!

Comment: This was helpful, I went back and slowly checked. Unfortunately all my references were correct, all the right lilypads were showing up. :( As I analyse it further it almost seems like they're disappearing when they hit the iAd banner??? but I'm really not sure why. The iAd banner shares the same [set Alpha] type of animation but I don't see why else that would happen??????????

Comment: It seems like you might NOT be using SpriteKit and are maybe reinventing the wheel a little bit here. IMO, you should be using SpriteKit for a game, especially the one you seem to be making. I haven't used iAd stuff but even so not sure why another view would be interacting like that.

Comment: You're right, I'm just using UIKit, which is probably bad. Should I take the time to learn sprite kit? Do you know any good tutorials to use to learn it?

Comment: You can start here: http://www.raywenderlich.com/42699/spritekit-tutorial-for-beginners